# Mongodb database for a tv series app, track use episode watching progress

Tags: database, mongodb, database-design

I am trying to make a tv series app. I stuck at design a collection to save use watched tv seasons and episodes. I am thinking a collection like this:

```
tv_id season_id  episodes
1     100        [1000,10001,10002]

tv_id season_id  episodes
1     101        [2000,20001,20002]
```

tv_id: use current watching tv show id
season_id: user watched season 1 id
episodes: use watched season 1 episodes

Is there a better design than this?

Comment: You can also add **user_id** to track which user is watching which show and for episodes which has been streamed partially , you can keep a track of those episodes with a separate attribute like **episodes_streaming** and when the episode is complete you update it to **episodes**

Comment: @RahulAnand Great idea. Add a separate attribute for episodes to watch.

Comment: You might need to build a recommendation system to get relevant episodes to watch for each user.